# How can I use a WEBAPI in .Net Application as a service reference?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, service-reference

I checked the below link, and i know that we can't use the WEBAPI as Service Reference.

[Reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

But i need to get the classes structure (metadata) from the service to use it in conversion by HTTP.

Since in the above reference, we can use HTTP to get data and convert using class that already created, and the service api i connect to, has huge number of classes and fields, so we need a way to download the classes or whole structure at least.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use swagger, but it has to be implemented in the service you are trying to connect. If you have such chance than you can generate C# client from swagger.
More in MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-2.2